FindMaximum, error in solution
The problem cannot be solved; the FindMaximum function throws an error/warning:
FindMaximum::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 10000 iterations.
I tried installing MaxIterations -> Infinity, but the error still does not go away.
Code:
Clear["`*"]

Ld = 1.862;
idnom = 1/Ld;

param = Solve[{u idnom + v == 1, u (3 idnom) + v == 1.3}, {u, v}];

f3[id_] := 
  Piecewise[{{id Ld, 
     id <= idnom}, {param[[1, 1, 2]] id + param[[1, 2, 2]], 
     id > idnom}}] ;

i3 = FindMaximum[{f3[id] iq, Sqrt[iq^2 + id^2] == 1.2, id > 0, 
   iq > 0}, {id, iq}, MaxIterations -> Infinity]

I really count on you, thank you.

I believe it is the non-differentiable kink of your function that is causing troubles to the maximizator. Luckily, in your case, you can use Maximize to find the global maximum without any warnings.
Maximize[{f3[id]  iq, Sqrt[iq^2 + id^2] == 1.2 && id > 0 && iq > 0}, {id, iq}]
(* {1.07361, {id -> 0.538498, iq -> 1.07318}} *)

To see the kink in action:
Plot[f3[id] Sqrt[1.2^2 - id^2], {id, 0, 1}]

attempts = Quiet@First@Last@Reap@FindMaximum[{f3[id] Sqrt[1.2^2 - id^2], 1.2 > id > 0}, id, 
            StepMonitor :> Sow[id], MaxIterations -> 200];

ListPlot[attempts, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"Step", "id"}]

You see how the maximizator gets trown off when it comes close to the the kink.

Alternatively, you can also use one of the unconstrained methods:
FindMaximum[{f3[id] Sqrt[1.2^2 - id^2]}, {id, 0.4}, Method -> "PrincipalAxis"]
(* {1.07311, {id -> 0.537057}} *)


,I'm really grateful to you.

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Use exact values, i.e., Rationalize
Ld = 1.862 // Rationalize;
idnom = 1/Ld;

param = Solve[{u  idnom + v == 1, u  (3  idnom) + v == 13/10}, {u, v}];

f3[id_] = 
  Piecewise[{{id  Ld, id <= idnom}, {param[[1, 1, 2]]  id + param[[1, 2, 2]], 
      id > idnom}}] // Simplify;

As Domen showed, use Maximize
i3 = Maximize[{f3[id]  iq, Sqrt[iq^2 + id^2] == 12/10, id > 0, iq > 0}, 
  {id, iq}]

(* {(2 Sqrt[6238349])/4655, {id -> 500/931, iq -> (2 Sqrt[6238349])/4655}} *)

i3 // N

(* {1.07311, {id -> 0.537057, iq -> 1.07311}} *)

Graphicly,
FunctionDomain[{f3[id]*Sqrt[(12/10)^2 - id^2], id > 0}, id]

(* 0 < id <= 6/5 *)

Plot[f3[id]*Sqrt[(12/10)^2 - id^2], {id, 0, 6/5},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{id, f3[id] iq} /. i3[[2]]]}]


